# ruby on rails form action showing dot

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using 
    link_to account.name, edit_account_path(account.id) 
which is generating 
    form class="edit_account" id="edit_account_2" action="/account.2" 
instead of
   form class="edit_account" id="edit_account_2" action="/account/2"

Can someone advise why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The link is unlikely to be relevant - this is probably because of the code that generates the form.

Comment: Can you show us at least part of the template code producing this?